# cannot find -lzbar when trying to run "python.exe .\setup.py bdist_wheel" on zbarlight

Tags: python, cygwin, mingw32, zbar, cygwin-64

I followed this:
https://ruvi-d.medium.com/getting-zbarlight-to-work-on-windows-a3dc643dba18
I got an error - "I get "ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)" so I changed `"elif msc_ver == '1900':"` to `"elif msc_ver == '1916':"` in the cygwinccompiler.py file. Now the error I get is `...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38 -LC:\zbarlight\venv\PCbuild\amd64 -lzbar -lpython38 -lvcruntime140 -o build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\zbarlight\_zbarlight.cp38-win_amd64.pyd C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzbar collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: there is no Mingw zbar package in Cygwin, so I do not see how Cygwin is relevant in your question

Comment: The tutorial I'm following (https://ruvi-d.medium.com/getting-zbarlight-to-work-on-windows-a3dc643dba18) mentions cygwin.

Comment: The `-lzbar` is telling the linker (ld.exe) to look for a file called `libzbar.a` in a user or system library folder. In cygwin you should convert windows paths to cygwin paths using e.g. `cygpath -u 'C:\zbarlight\venv\PCbuild\amd64'`. BUT it looks like you are using mingw64 instead of cygwin. In either case make sure the library file and/or its .dll actually exists where you say it is using the `-L` option.

Comment: step 1 is "Install MinGW-W64". And another step asks to "Create file called distutils.cfg with the text
    [build]
    compiler = mingw32

    Apply this patch https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff to the cygwinccompiler.py file in the same folder"

Comment: I created the whl file and installed it, now I get "DLL load failed while importing _zbarlight"